# How to fix React state update on click button twice?

Tags: reactjs

I am working with webpack and react. I create count increment in my application, but when i click on button state not changed, But when i click again than count increment or you can say state updated. Please check my code below and let me know where i am wrong.

You can check in below image i clicked twice but count is 1.

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Count = () => {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function click() {
    console.log("clicked");
    setCount(count++);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={click} className="btn btn-primary">
        Click here
      </button>
      <h3>{count}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Count;
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: can you please confirm one of the correct answers so people know this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok you have one of three solutions:

- pass a function to your set state: like `setCount(prevState => prevState +1)`
- do a pre-increment instead like: `setCount(++count)`
- add manually with using increment like: `setCount(count + 1)`

your code does not work because you are using a post-increment operation, which uses the value then increment 1 to it which caused the confusion you are currently facing.

Comment: you're absolutely welcome, we've all been there. it was the pain of my existence when i first started work with react and states xD

Answer (score 3):

In React, state update is asynchronous.
You should write:

```
setCount(previousCount => previousCount + 1);
```

To learn more: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

`counter++` is post incremental and it uses the count value first and then plus 1 to it. so, first time you click on the button, it sets count with `count` and then add 1 to it. to use pre incremental `++count` or `count + 1` instead of `count++`

Answer (score 1):

Use previous state

```
 function click() {
    console.log("clicked");
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount+1);
    //or
    //setCount(count+1);
  }
```